# How can I fix the following tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tikz picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=-3.5cm,yshift=0cm,scale=1]
      \draw [draw=black, line width=0.35mm, fill=red] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) -- (2.5,1.5) -- (2.5, 0) node[midway,above] {} -- (0,0) node[midway,right] {};
      \node at (0.75,1.5) {};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=-3.5cm,yshift=0cm,scale=1]
      \draw [draw=black, line width=0.35mm, fill=red] (2.7,0) -- (2.7,1.5) -- (5.2,1.5) -- (5.2, 0) node[midway,above] {} -- (0,0) node[midway,left] {};
      \node at (0.75,1.5) {};
    \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

1. I would like to add some writing above the rectangles, but using the available nodes there (with {}) places the text where I wouldn't expect. (especially for midway,above).
2. I would like to have a writing in the middle of the rectangle.
3. There is a strange line connecting the two rectangles, and I am not sure what is its source (at the bottom). Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 3mm,
box/.style = {% definition of rectangle as node
    draw, line width=0.35mm, fill=red,
  text width=23mm, minimum height=15mm, align=center,
  inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt}
                    ]
\node (box1) [box, label=above:label 1] {text 1};
\node (box2) [box, right=of box1,
              label=above:label 2]   {text 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I take very different approach in drawing your rectangles. The `scope` is not intended for positioning single element of picture. For this I use TikZ library `positioning`, and set distance between nodes to 3mm. Since rectangles are drawn by nodes, you can easy add text in them as well ad labels.

Property of "rectangles", i.e. nodes, are defined with style `box`, where is determined it width, height, text position, fill etc.

It is true, that TikZ manual is huge, however, it is very worth to read thir part: *TikZ is kein Ziechenprogram*.